# Using Grunt & grunt-uncss to remove unused css styles on a large scale Magento website

Tags: javascript, magento, automation, gruntjs

I have used the javascript task runner **Grunt** to test out removing unused CSS styles from a single page using grunt-uncss. This works well, however I am trying to determine the best way to use this on a large scale dynamic framework such as Magento (which has thousands of files).

Could anyone determine the best way to use Grunt with Magento without having to determine loads of individual configurations? Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote grunt-uncss. The way I would approach a large scale multi-page project using UnCSS is to first take a look at the number of unique templates and page types you may have.

For example, you might have distinct templates that are used for say - dashboards, profile pages and so on. For each of these, pick one page/URL that is representative of the best use of that template and that will probably leave you with about 10 or so URLs that are generally good to run through grunt-uncss.

Run them, try replacing your site-wide CSS with the trimmed down version we generate and tweak as necessary.

Comment: i feel humbled you came to respond my question thanks Addy - i will let you know how I get on :)